# Wait for response from request before returning

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to create a function with a GET request that returns a portion of the data from the GET request. However, it keeps returning before the data is retrieved, so I keep getting "undefined". How can I set this up so it actually waits for the data to be set before returning?

```
let getInfo = async () => {
  const request = net.request({
    url: URL
  })
  
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // Promise being here DOES work
    request.on('response', (response) => {
      response.on('data', (chunk) => {

        //return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { //Promise being here does NOT work
          let body = JSON.parse(chunk)
          let info = body.data
          if (info){
            resolve(info);
          }
          reject();
        //})
      });

    });

    request.write('')
    request.end()
  }).then(data => {
    console.log("From then: "+data)
    return data
  })
}

getInfo().then(data => {
  console.log("From outside: "+data)
})
```

**Edit:** This is the updated version that still does not work. I am trying to use the [native electron method](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/client-request) and I don't see why this doesn't work. The "From then:" part displays the info correctly. But when run "From outside:" it prints undefined. Does the issue have anything to do with the `response.on` being nested inside the `request.on`?

**Solution:** As @NidhinDavid showed in his answer, the issue was that the promise was inside the `'response'` listener. Moving the `'GET'` request from start to finish inside the Promise fixed it to giving the correct output. I have updated my code to reflect that for future individuals.

Comment: This is basics and some googling willl give you the answer. As for starter try using `console.log(await getInfo())`

Comment: Can you give the reference from where you are importing the net ?

Comment: @NidhinDavid I have googled it several times, looking at dozens of pages and tried many different things. What you suggested was the first thing I tried, and it did not work.

Comment: @Bazoogle I added an answer to help you out of the fustration. Hope it helps!

Comment: Don't update your question to not have a problem anymore, thats what the answer section is for. Now the question doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find the `net` module and the one which is included with Nodejs do not have request method. So to get the similar concept of event emiters and promise I am using `http` module and doing a http request to fetch json and parse it

```
'use strict'

var https = require('https');


const getInfo = async () => {

  // create a new promise chain
  // remember it is a chain, if one return is omitted
  // then the chain is broken
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    var options = {
      host: 'support.oneskyapp.com',
      path: '/hc/en-us/article_attachments/202761727/example_2.json'
    };

    // start the request
    https.request(options, function (response) {
      var str = '';

      // data arrives in chunks
      // chunks needs to be stitched together before parsing
      response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        str += chunk;
      });

      // response body obtained
      // resolve (aka return) the result
      // or parse it, or do whatever you want with it
      response.on('end', function () {
        resolve(str)

      });

      // errors are another event
      // listen for errors and reject when they are encountered
      response.on('error', function (err) {
        reject(err)
      })
    }).end()
  })
}

//*********************************************
// using async await
//*********************************************
// if this is the entry point into app
// then top-level async approach required
(async ()=>{
 try{
   let data = await getInfo()
   console.log("From ASYNC AWAIT ")
   console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data)))
 }
 catch (err) {
   console.log("operation failed, error: ", err)
 }
})();

//************************************************
// using promise chains
//************************************************
getInfo()
.then((data)=>{
  console.log("FROM PROMISE CHAIN ")
  console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data)))
})
.catch((err)=>{
  console.log("operation failed, error: ", err)
})
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! The promise being inside the `'response'` listener was the issue. I just moved the entire `GET` request to inside the promise and now it works like you'd expect it to! I am still using electrons native method, but you having your request sent from within the promise made me try that, and it worked. You're a life saver.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let getInfo = () => {
  let info;

  const request = net.request({
    url: URL
  })

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.on('response', (response) => {
      response.on('data', (chunk) => {
        request.write('')
        request.end()
        let body = JSON.parse(chunk)
        info = body.data
        if (info) {
          resolve(info)
        } else {
          reject('Something went wrong');
        }
      });
    });
  })
}

getInfo()
  .then(data => {
    // this will be your info object
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // this will log 'Something went wrong' in case of any error
    console.log(err)
  })
```

You need to return inside your, `on` type event handler. Read more about asynchronous code and synchronous code [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-from-callbacks-to-async-await-1cc090ddad99/)

Comment: I tried that as well. and it printed "undefined" still

Comment: Do check if `data` is a valid key on the `body` object as well

Comment: Also, can you share more of your code, so that I can test it locally, there is a possibility you need to return the promise and things will work well for you. Any specific reason for not using fetch ?

Comment: If I `console.log(info)` from inside the response listener, and `return info` right after that, it will print fine, but the log will show `undefined` and then `{correct info}`. I cannot put `request.write` and `request.end` inside the listener, because it will never be triggered. There is no particular reason for me to use this method, it's just that I am building an electron app and thought to use the electron native method.

Comment: Okay got it, give me a min and I will update the answer then try that

Comment: Try the updated snippet and let me know, if you encounter any other problem as well

Comment: I really thought that would work. It's doing the exact same thing for some reason. I will print once from trying to call it, and once from inside to make sure it got the data. It will print undefined, then milliseconds after it will print the data I want. I don't understand why with my promise it isn't waiting for the data.

Comment: I guess you are still calling `console.log(getInfo())`, it can't print `undefined` from inside the `then` thing. Please check, you might be missing one or the other thing, most probably it should work. I would be more than happy to help if you could provide more code. I can initiate one on one chat room here on stackoverflow if you want to share code privately.

Comment: Yes, let's message. I don't think I can initiate it because I do not have enough rep.

Comment: I tried but you should have at least 20 reputation to talk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233116/discussion-between-nikhil-singh-and-bazoogle).

Comment: I think this snippet as is should result in error - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`  the whole point is you should not break the promise chain. here the promise should be returend from getInfo()

Comment: @NidhinDavid Thanks for pointing it out, I completely missed it. Now, I have updated the snippet and it should be good to go. Btw it was nowhere giving any type error. Bazoogle now you can try the updated snippet without importing axios.

Answer (score 0):

Tyr this, it might works for you,

```
let info;
const getInfo = async (_url)=>{

const response = await fetch(_url);
const data = await response.json();
info = data; 
} ;

const url = "some url";

getInfo(url);
console.log(info);
```

Async function always returns a promise, so either consume that promise or internally await the data and assign it to some variable.
Check for the valid data required in info by logging it to the console.

Comment: Electron doesn't have fetch natively. I could add it, but I was trying to keep it with just the native method for efficiency  https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/client-request